# Usage of "owing to"

Tags: word-usage, usage

I would like to start my formal letter with the phrase:

> I am writing owing to the fact, that...

But I'm not sure about using **owing to**. Is that correct?

Comment: What's wrong with 'because'?

Comment: Or even just "I am writing **to** (inform, ask, whatever)..." don't overcomplicate it even in formal writing.

Comment: Without knowing what follows it is hard to say whether you even need "I am writing". After all they are reading your letter so they know you wrote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of how good the writing is, this is not grammatically correct. It should be "due to the fact," but either way, it is very awkward. I would recommend changing it to "I am writing because..."